# Why is my date input not reading the model value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm a server side guy trying to teach myself a bit of CSS, Javascript, jQuery etc.  I have written a little test project that loads up a model and displays the values in simple text boxes.  Works OK, as you can see:

[image]

But of course, I want to display those dates appropriately.  So let me change those input types to "date".  Here's the Razor code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { @type="date", @id="ondate" })
```

Well, that worked.... sort of.  I mean, it now displays as a date picker... but it's no longer displaying the model's date!

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: An upvote from me for lovely formatted screenshots! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type="date"` attribute renders the browsers HTML5 datepicker. In order for this to work correctly, the format needs to be `yyyy-MM-dd` (ISO format), so it needs to be

```c#
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @type="date" })
```

Alternatively you can set data attributes on the property

```c#
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

and use

```c#
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date)
```

which adds the `type="date"` attribute and uses the correct format.

Side notes:

1. The HTML5 datepicker is only supported in recent versions of Chrome
2. Using `EditorFor()` (in MVC-4) will not allow you to set the `id`
   attribute, but its not clear why you would need to change the
   default `id="Date"` to `id="ondate"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { @type = "date", @id = "ondate", @value = Model.Date.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy") })%>
```