# Why is my date control empty when page loads?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, datepicker

My Date control is always empty when the page loads.
Why is that?
There is data in the database for that control.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "control-    label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { type = "Date" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, new { type = "Date" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add more details - controller's code and sample model data.

Comment: Are you populating your StartDate within your controller for the model that you're passing to the view?

Comment: Your specifying the input as `type="date"` which renders the HTML5 datepicker (note its only supported in Chrome) which means the date must be in ISO format (`yyyy-MM-dd`). Add the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute to your property

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Please don't provide answers in the comments. You're absolutely correct about the problem and how to fix it, but now someone needs to either rip off you comment or this will go unanswered indefinitely.

Comment: @Chris, I was going to find a suitable dupe. I'll add an answer shortly :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my date input not reading the model value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356115/why-is-my-date-input-not-reading-the-model-value)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Understandable, but there's nothing wrong with providing an answer and then voting to close as a dupe. That way, if it never ends up being closed, at least it still has an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As noted by @Coulton, make sure you're actually populating your model's `StartDate` and `EndDate` properties on your controller before rendering the page. Also if you use the `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` flag on your class you could discard the `TextBoxFor` helper and instead used the `EditorFor` helper.

Examples for populating the data attributes before a Create or an Edit view (Which seems to be the view you're trying to build there):

Controller.cs, `ganho.Data` is a DateTime attribute with a `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`  flag

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        // Omitted code
        var result = from ganho in db.Ganhos
                     where ganho.GanhoID == id.Value
                     where ganho.Usuario.Id == user.Id
                     select new GanhoEditViewModel
                     {
                         GanhoID = ganho.GanhoID,
                         Valor = ganho.Valor,
                         Comentario = ganho.Comentario,
                         Data = ganho.Data,
                         Descricao = ganho.Descricao,
                         Tipo = ganho.Tipo
                     };
        if (result.Count() < 1)
        {
            // 404, no such item exists
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(result.Single());
    }
```

Edit.chtml

```
<!-- Hidden Code, not relevant to the question -->
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "dataInput"} })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
</div>
```

In case you're setting up for a Create view, you can initialize the field like this:

Controller.cs, `ganho.Data` is my DateTime attribute which the user will display a placeholder data.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new Ganho()
    {
        // ...
        Data = DateTime.Now,    // Using the current date and time as a placeholder
        // ...
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Please note that in all examples I'm using Strongy Typed views!